# In a yocto recipe, what selects the release to download from the GitHub repository?

Tags: git, yocto, github

I'm using yocto to build my custom Linux distribution. I need to add `hiredis` to my distribution. [hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis) is a minimalistic C client library for the Redis database, and I need it to access Redis by a C application.

#### The recipe `hiredis_0.14.0.bb`

In my yocto build system there is the recipe `hiredis_0.14.0.bb` stored in the folder `meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-extended/hiredis` so in the meta layer `meta-openembedded`.

The content of the recipe is the following:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Minimalistic C client library for Redis"
HOMEPAGE = "http://github.com/redis/hiredis"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"
SECTION = "libs"
DEPENDS = "redis"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=d84d659a35c666d23233e54503aaea51"
SRCREV = "685030652cd98c5414ce554ff5b356dfe8437870"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/redis/hiredis;protocol=git \
           file://0001-Makefile-remove-hardcoding-of-CC.patch"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit autotools-brokensep pkgconfig

EXTRA_OEMAKE = "PREFIX=${prefix} LIBRARY_PATH=${baselib}"

# By default INSTALL variable in Makefile is equal to 'cp -a', which preserves
# ownership and causes host-user-contamination QA issue.
# And PREFIX defaults to /usr/local.
do_install_prepend() {
  export INSTALL='cp -r'
}
```

#### The Git Fetcher download the version `0.14.0` of hiredis

If I execute the command:

```
> bitbake hiredis
```

the `hiredis` code is fetched by [GitHub](https://github.com/redis/hiredis) and correctly compiled. The version on the code downloaded from GitHub is the 0.14.0, while the `SRC_URI` is set to:

```
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/redis/hiredis;protocol=git \
           file://0001-Makefile-remove-hardcoding-of-CC.patch"
```

This value for `SRC_URI` means that is using the [Git Fetcher](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.4/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-fetching.html#git-fetcher-git) and are not specified parameters `branch` or `rev` and this means that the values of this parameters is `master`.

The only reference to version `0.14.0` is in the name of the recipe (hiredis_`0.14.0`.bb) so it is chosen the version `0.14.0` because the value of the `PV` variable is `0.14.0` (the `PV` value is set by the name of the recipe).

#### My question

Why the fetched version of hiredis library is `0.14.0` and not the latest?

Comment: [`685030652cd98c5414ce554ff5b356dfe8437870`](https://github.com/redis/hiredis/commit/685030652cd98c5414ce554ff5b356dfe8437870) appears to be the commit hash for the `0.14.0` release. Do you know why you are specifying that particular hash for `SRCREV`?  If this comment answers the question, then you may want to write an answer expanding on it in the box below.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks. By the URL `https://github.com/mnunberg/hiredis/commit/685030652cd98c5414ce554ff5b356dfe8437870` I get the version 0.14.0. I didn't know the concept of commit hash. The variable `SRCREV=685030652cd98c5414ce554ff5b356dfe8437870` is set in the original recipe present in my Yocto build system. If I will better understand the question I'll write an answer to my question.

Comment: Ah you should really fresh up your foot knowledge if you want to work with openembedded. Kinda hard to understand much without that!

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. Thank you I know very well my little knowledge about many topics.. I'm here to improve my knowledge and I hope someone will help me :). In my previous comment I would say "If I will better understand the problem I'll write an answer to my question".

Comment: Looking forward!

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. I think I have found a possible solution.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think I have found a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kusalananda tells in his comment:

> the release of `hiredis` downloaded from GitHub is selected by the commit hash assigned to the variable `SRCREV`.

For example to fetch and compile the release 1.0.1 of `hiredis` I can add to the folder `my-meta-layer/recipes-extended/hiredis` a file `hiredis_%.bbappend` and, in it, set the value of `SRC_REV` equal to the commit hash of the release 1.0.1 (that is `8d1bfac4640fe90cd6f800d09b7f53e886569b98`).
In the case of the recipe `hiredis_0.14.0.bb` showed by the question I need also change the value of the variable `SRC_URI`.

The content of the added file `hiredis_%.bbappend` is showed below:

```
# SRC_URI for release 1.0.1
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/redis/hiredis;protocol=https;branch=master"

# Commit Hash of release 1.0.1
SRCREV = "8d1bfac4640fe90cd6f800d09b7f53e886569b98"

inherit cmake
```

#### Description of the bbappend file

- by the `SRC_URI` value I have set the value of parameters `protocol=https;branch=master` of the Git Fetcher (instead in the original recipe their values were `protocol=git` and `branch` is not set)
- set `SRCREV` equal to the commit hash of release 1.0.1
- add the instruction `inherit cmake` because the release 1.0.1 uses CMake

#### My solution not work for all release of `hiredis`

I think that my solution could be a general solution of the problem presented in the question for many yocto recipes, but in the case of the `hiredis` it doesn't always work.
I have tested the solution for some releases with the following result:

- ok for release 0.14.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2
- **not work** for release 0.14.1